# Extract phone numbers from email using python 2.7 regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the phone numbers from many files of emails. I wrote regex code to extract them but I got the results for just one format.

```
PHONERX = re.compile("(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})")

phonenumber = re.findall(PHONERX,content)
```

when I reviewed the data, I found there were many formats for phone numbers.

How can I extract all the phone numbers that have these format together:

```
800-569-0123
1-866-523-4176
(324)442-9843
(212) 332-1200
713/853-5620
713 853-0357
713 837 1749
```

This link is a sample for the dataset. the problem is sometime the phone numbers regex extract from the messageId and other numbers in the email 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pw2yfesim4ejncf/AADwdWpJJTuxaJTPfha38OdRa?dl=0

Comment: it looks better now thank you for edited it

Comment: If the commas aren't included, [edit] yourself, please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use:

```
\(?(?:1-)?\b[2-9][0-9]{2}\)?[-. \/]?[2-9][0-9]{2}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b
```

Which will match all your examples + ignore false positives, like:

```
113 837 1749
222 2222 22222
```

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/HvlVBV/6)

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/A8RQcC)

Comment: Can you please define *no result*?  both demos work as expected. Did you get any errors?

Comment: where should I use this re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
PHONERX = re.compile("\(?(?:1-)?\b[2-9][0-9]{2}\)?[-. /]?[2-9][0-9]{2}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b")
phonenumber = re.findall(PHONERX,content, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

Comment: You can use the code from https://ideone.com/A8RQcC, it works as intended.

Comment: Thank you, for you answer. it worked perfectly in your example but it didn't work with me. i dont know why. I think because i'm extracting from many files of emails

Comment: I may know what's going on, can you post a sample of the email's source? Please also include the headers. On which telephone formar  did your regex work?

Comment: ok I'll update it now, my old regex extract from the messageID number too from the header

Comment: I just updated the question and I added the sample in the link

Comment: I've tested my regex with the new email source and it   works as expected, it only extracts the phone #'s.

Comment: Yeah and I tested in the regex demo it worked but it didn't work with me when I tried with all data. I just update the link with more than 5 email files. if you can try it works with more than one email. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include all the possibilities using a logical OR. You can use following regex:

```
(?:\(\d+\)\s?\d*|\d+)([-\/ ]\d+){1,3}
```

see the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBndd6/2)

For using with `re.findall()` use non-captured group:

```
(?:\(\d+\)\s?\d*|\d+)(?:[-\/ ]\d+){1,3}
```

Comment: I tried it but i didn't get a result for fall phone number. the result that I got look like this phonenumber=[' 14', '-7796', '-3490'])

Comment: @Ash That's because the `re.findall` will give you the result of captured groups. If you want to get the whole match you need to use non-captured group by adding `?:`. Check out the update.

Comment: I just apdated the question with code i'm using, I'll try yours again thank you

Comment: your code looks perfect as I saw in the demo but I don't why it didn't work the same with me. I think because of the dataset which are many files of emails. 
thank you